# Camera module not getting detected

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspbian-jessie, raspicam

**I get this error when I run 'raspistill -t 2000 -o image.png -e png
'**

mmal: Cannot read cameara info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component

mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly

Comment: Camera option is enabled and had tried updating/upgrading the firmware

Comment: Recheck the cable connections?  Also, be sure to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure you are running with the latest software.

Comment: I had the same problem. I ran everything that was said above. It finally worked after I checked the connection between the camera an the board.

Answer (score 7):

I would double check that the camera is correctly connected at both ends and not loose, and that it is enabled via the RPI config menu. The RPi+ camera draws about 260 mA more current than the board so you need a large enough power supply to support the added load.

After the camera is enabled, you also need a reboot. Check that `/boot/config.txt` contains the lines:

```
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

This will confirm if the camera is properly enabled. If the GPU memory is too small the camera will not work. Also try running a `sudo rpi-update`.

There are two ways of accessing the camera: Through the Broadcom specific MMAL library, which is used by `raspistill` and `raspivid`, or via Video4Linux2, which is a cross platform standard. If you have V4L2 installed then you can try to access the camera through that driver to see what happens. V4L2 should come pre-installed on the latest Raspberian OS. You can check by typing `which v4l2-ctl`. Normally it is `/usr/bin/v4l2-ctl`, otherwise try a `sudo apt-get install v4l-utils`.

To enable it to access the camera, you should first load the driver module by typing

`sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`.

This should create a camera device at `/dev/video0`.
You can then get information by typing

`v4l2-ctl --all`.

This will list a huge amount of information about any cameras in the system and their settings and drivers. And by typing

`v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --list-formats-ex`

you can determine the list of frame sizes and frame rates supported.

There's also the possibility that you have a faulty camera board.

Comment: `This should create a camera device at /dev/video0` For me it does not, as `v4l2-ctl --all` outputs `Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.` Been on this for two entire days: this camera problem is a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the camera is disabled eg. using a new image. To enable the camera run:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

At the blue screen, select *interface* point and enable camera.

And finally reboot the raspberry.

```
sudo reboot now
```